# Аннотирование типов - введение своего класса и отображение подсказки в PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, typing

Ввожу аннотирование типов в свой старый проект. В том числе есть функции, где передаются объекты моих классов. Я их пишу напрямую, но PyCharm подсвечивает в подсказке вместо моего класса `Any`. Подозреваю, что делаю что-то не так. Собственно пример ниже на скриншоте.

Код из пример:

```
self.forms38: Optional[Dict[str, Forms38]] = self.get_forms38(forms38)
```

[image: Ошибка в аннотировании]

Comment: Может, лучше аннотировать саму функцию, а не переменную, куда кладётся результат из неё? Какая у Вас версия PyCharm? У меня в `PyCharm 2020.3.5 Pro` всё корректно работает: [скрин](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4xj4.png).

Comment: 1. Функция тоже аннотирована. 2. Попробовал ваш пример, он у меня тоже заработал. Единственная разница, у меня класс Form38 лежит в другом файле, но я его импортировал через import.

Comment: Версия PyCharm 2021.1

Comment: Все, нашел опечатку в коде, которая все решила